# Why is the socket number incremented by one in libssh2 x11 forwarding example?

Tags: x11, socket, forwarding

I am looking to x11 forwarding example in libssh2 source (example/x11.c).
In the function x11_send_receive I see this code:

```
rc = select(sock + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeval_out);
if(rc > 0) {
    memset((void *)buf, 0, bufsize);

    /* Data in sock*/
    rc = read(sock, buf, bufsize);
    if(rc > 0) {
        libssh2_channel_write(channel, buf, rc);
    }
    else {
        free(buf);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the socked is incremented (+ 1) in the select statement.
Can someone explain this?

Probably it is related to listening sockets - I see two:

```
# netstat -lxn | grep /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     32746    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     32745    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

sock is connecting to path /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 (without @)...
So what is in the background?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [the `select` call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) requires:

> `nfds`   This argument should be set to the highest-numbered file
> descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.

`sock` contains the highest-numbered file descriptor in the sets, so the first argument to `select` is `sock + 1`.